# What to do with old question

Tags: discussion, old-questions

I posted this question: [USB recognized but not available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26259/usb-recognized-but-not-available) a long time ago. Because of circumstances, I was unable to keep testing the suggestions, so I abandoned it.

I think the question itself could be useful (as reference), but as it will never be able to have a correct answer, I think its better to close it or delete it.

What should be done?

Comment: I gather the problem is not reproducible anymore? If so, it should be closed as "can't be reproduced". Deleting it or not deleting it is up to you and you only, but remember that a big enough number of deleted posts (proportional to your overall number of posts) could get you a ban from asking questions.

Comment: But I don't see `can't be reproduced` option for "close". I only see: `duplicate of... ` , `off-topic because… `, `unclear what you're asking `, `too broad` and `primarily opinion-based`

Comment: Close -> off-topic because... -> This describes **a problem that can't be reproduced** [...]. I gather that's the case?

Comment: @kos deletion doesn't count.

Comment: Thank you. I will do that.

Comment: @Braiam In this case no because the question is older than 30 days, but in general a high number of deleted posts can trigger an automatic ban: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/302251. And AFAIK the threshold is proportional to the number of questions / answers posted in total, so it's easy to cross it if you have a low number of posts (however again, this question wouldn't count, just to let OP know about that).

Comment: I didn't know about such rules (thanks for letting me know).

Comment: @kos err no http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/792066